# Timestamp while recording video

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage, avcapturesession

I require timestamp [ Date and Time on Top] same as this App while recording video: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timestamp-photo-video-free/id941119020?mt=8.

I added the overlay view successfully, but I need to see the same overlay while recording video similar to attached image. I tried Avcapturesession method as well as GPUImage filter.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some information about the problems you experienced when trying this with the Avcapturesession method? There doesn't seem to be a lot to go on here.

Comment: I am able to capture and save the video in Photo album. But without timestamp which is shown in above screen.

Comment: Would adding some code help, do you think?

Comment: I used  [PreviewLayer insertSublayer:adddView.layer above:[CameraView layer]]; this line to insert an additional overlay view while recording

Comment: @halfer Any update regarding above comments. Your help will really appreciated

Comment: It's not my area of expertise, so no - my comments were based on my opinion that the post was not sufficiently detailed to attract quality answers (and that's still my view, to be honest). Is there anything more you can add to it? I suspect you'll need to do a substantial research session `:-)`.

Comment: i also same issue.. i need time stamp for second also change

Comment: @user5421830  Any update with the above code? anyone who was able to figure it out?